# How do I traverse a memory block in a struct with pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

**Goal:**
Traverse the `vertices` memory block in the `Heap` struct.

**Errors:** I get `expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token` when trying to access `vertices`. Also, `‘vertices’ was not declared in this scope`.

**Header:**

```
typedef struct Heap *PriorityQueue_t;
typedef struct HeapItem *PriorityItem_t;

PriorityQueue_t Init(int max_capacity, int source_vertex);
```

**Implementation:**

```
#include "heap.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct Heap
{
  int size;
  PriorityItem_t vertices;
};

struct HeapItem
{
  int id;
  int distance;
};

PriorityQueue_t Init(int max_capacity, int source_vertex)
{
  PriorityQueue_t Q;

  Q = (PriorityQueue_t)malloc(sizeof(PriorityQueue_t));
  Q->vertices = (PriorityItem_t)malloc(sizeof(PriorityItem_t)*max_capacity);

  Q->size = max_capacity;

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < Q->size; i++)
  {
    Q->(vertices + i)->id = i; //Errors on this line.
    Q->(vertices + i)->distance = INT_MAX;
  }
  Q->(vertices + source_vertex)->distance = 0;

  return Q;
}
```

Comment: BTW `PriorityQueue_t` is a typedeffed pointer (which is a bad habit, IMHO. For human readers, reading an extra `*` is easier than remembering yet another name for (basically) the same thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've placed the parens in the wrong place. Try this:

```
    (Q->vertices + i)->id = i; //Errors on this line.
    (Q->vertices + i)->distance = INT_MAX;
  }
  (Q->vertices + source_vertex)->distance = 0;
```

Comment: The compiler errors are gone. Please explain why this works. What was I doing wrong conceptually?

Comment: After `->` and `.` you must have the name of a structure/union member. You didn't. Also `vertices` in `(vertices + i)` is not known because you don't have any local or global variable (or function) by that name. Basically, with that paren you severed the link between the pointer to the structure, `Q`, and the member of the structure, `vertices`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Q->(vertices + i)->id = i; //Errors on this line.
Q->(vertices + i)->distance = INT_MAX;
Q->(vertices + source_vertex)->distance = 0;
```

You can't do that like that...

```
Q->vertices[i].id = i;
(Q->vertices + i)->distance = INT_MAX;
(*(Q->vertices + source_vertex)).distance = 0;  // Not sensible, but legal
```

Comment: Why is there a `*`? If you want `*` there, use `.` with it.

Comment: Because `(*(a+i))` is one way of transforming `a[i]`...the original version of the syntax was incorrect, but the revised code passes a compiler.

Comment: Yep, the comment was about the first couple of versions of your answer. It's now correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a lot of parentheses by using plain indexing and removing the casts:

```
PriorityQueue_t Init(int max_capacity, int source_vertex)
{
  PriorityQueue_t Q;

  Q = malloc(sizeof *Q);
  Q->vertices = malloc(max_capacity * sizeof *Q->vertices);

  Q->size = max_capacity;

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < Q->size; i++)
  {
    Q->vertices[i].id = i;
    Q->vertices[i].distance = INT_MAX;
  }
  // maybe add next line: 
  // assert (source_vertex >=0 && source_vertex < Q->size);
  Q->vertices[source_vertex].distance = 0;

  return Q;
}
```